# How would I anonymous push username information to Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've tried a few things, but nothing seems to work properly. I'm utilizing anonymous users and I have the User class in parse working fine, as it creates an autogenerated username for the current device utilizing the app.

I'd just like to attach the currentuser to my "createdBy" column alongside all the data in parse and I'm quite stumped as most things I've tried have failed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this in viewDidLoad?

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
    user["createdBy"] = user.username
    user.saveInBackground()
}
```

It will push username to parse.com